# Cannot change files after creating a symlink in Windows 8.1

Tags: permissions, symbolic-link

I created a symlink in Windows 8.1 (to point my documents folder to dropbox).
Since then I am no longer able to write or delete contents in that folder.

I always get an access denied error (but I am the admin). I tried taking ownership but it didn't work.

Also, if I go into the Authorization tab, it looks like the Admin (which is the group my user is in) can do everything but that's not the case.

Also, everything is disabled. How can I get edit access to my documents folder again?

[image: Here's my permission dialog. I cannot change anything]

Thanks.

Comment: Are you accessing via the simlink or the folder itself? Do the permissions come back when you delete the simlink? How did you create the simlink? `mklink /J link target`?

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply. I used mklink to create the Simlink but I'm not sure of the exact parameters I used. I removed the link (by deleting it in Windows explorer) but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not to do with the simlink.

The check-boxes are greyed out when the permissions are inherited from the parent folder.

Click `Security`, `Advanced` then in `Advanced Security Settings` click `Edit`. Uncheck `Include Inheritable Permissions From Parent`.

Comment: Hello, It ended up being a problem with my antivirus (Bitdefender). After restarting my machine everything started working again.